# Arrays indexing

Tags: python, arrays

I have two variables, lim1 and lim2, that are indexes of a matrix. They indicate a part of the matrix that should be filled with zeros:

```
matrix[j,lim1:lim2] = 0
```

However, in some cases, lim1 and lim2 exceed the limits of the matrix, i.e., they are less than zero or greater than n (where n = len(matrix[j,:]). In these cases I must use 0 or n instead of lim1 or lim2.

To test these limits, I am currently using the code:

```
lim1 = something
if lim1 < 0:
   lim1 = 0
elif lim1 > n:
   lim1 = n

lim2 = something
if lim2 < 0:
   lim2 = 0
elif lim2 > n:
   lim2 = n

matrix[j,lim1:lim2] = 0
```

Is there any more compact way to test these limits? For example, in IDL it would be written as:

```
matrix[lim1>0<n:lim2>0<n] = 0
```

This code repeats a lot, so it would be very useful to write it more concisely.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should use numpy

Comment: Shouldn't your upper limit be n-1 instead of n?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `min` and `max` to cap a value. So, the code can be written a bit more concisely like this:

```
matrix[j, min(max(0,lim1),n):min(max(0,lim2),n)] = 0
```